# Untracked file has disappeared from local directory

Tags: git, github, gitignore

On my project I have a `.gitignore` file which, among other things, lists `public` as an untracked folder (so public does not show up on the Github repo).

The other day I checked out a separate branch from master and removed public from `.gitignore`.

When I pushed the this new branch to Github it worked fine and I could see `public` tracked on the new branch.

But now `public` has completely vanished from all other branches, locally of course, including master. Has anyone encountered a similar issue? I'm sure someone has so this may be a redundancy but I don't know a better way to word such a strange issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely normal based on what you said you did.

Files are not tracked-vs-untracked based on *branches*.  Branches, or more precisely, your branch *names*,<sup>1</sup> are entirely irrelevant.  Each branch name selects one specific *commit*, however, and *commits* are relevant.  A commit, once made, is always the same, forever—but the branch names move about, based on what you tell Git to do with them, so the *branch names* don't matter: it's the commits that matter.

**A file you're working with while using Git is said to be *tracked* if and only if that file is currently in Git's *index*.**  The really surprising, and a little mind-bending, part of all of this is that tracked-ness of a file is not even a property of a commit.  It tends to be controlled *by* a commit because we use `git checkout` or `git switch` to *extract* a commit.  This **fills in Git's index from that commit** and this is what causes the file to now be a tracked file.

**The files you see and work with are not *in* Git.**  This is the real key: when people use Git, they tend to think that the files they have in their work-tree are "Git files" or "files in a branch" or something along those lines.  This is just wrong.  The files you work with—the ones in your work-tree—*may* have been *extracted from* a commit.  **The files stored inside commits are in Git.**  They get transferred from one Git to another when you use `git push` or `git fetch`.  **The files in your work-tree are not in Git.**

If Git copied a file *out* of a commit, to put it into your work-tree, when you ran `git checkout master` or `git checkout mybranch` or `git checkout c0ffee900d`, Git copied that file into Git's index first.  (Let's say that all three of these names select commit `c0ffee900d`.)  So now that file exists in three places (and maybe more commits as well, but at least these three):

- the file is in the commit, which you can see with, e.g., `git show c0ffee900d:public/foo.html`;
- the file is in Git's index, which you can see with `git show :public/foo.html`;
- and the file is in your work-tree, which you can see because your regular computer programs show you these files, and work with them.

But suppose you now `git checkout` some *other* commit.  Pick any other commit, by hash ID, or by branch name.  Let's say that this *other* commit *does not* store the file `public/foo.html` in it.  Git now sees that you're moving from some commit that *does* have `public/foo.html` in it, to one that doesn't.  So Git:

- removes `:public/foo.html` from Git's index, and
- **removes `public/foo.html` from your work-tree**

because you told it to.

---

<sup>1</sup>See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  The word *branch* is ambiguous: sometimes people use it to mean *the tip commit of a branch*, in which case, the commit itself is relevant, and you found it by using a branch name, so in that sense, your branch name mattered.  But tomorrow, you might change the hash ID associated with the branch name, and that could change everything.  You cannot change *anything* about the one specific commit, though, and you can always obtain *that* commit, using its hash ID.

---

#### What you can do about all of this

There is still a copy of `c0ffee900d:public/foo.html` in the *repository*.  That copy is as permanent as commit `c0ffee900d`: as long as the *commit* is in the repository, so is that copy of the file.  But that file isn't in your *work-tree* any more because it was tracked—it was in Git's index—and you told Git to switch over to commit `badcafe`, or whatever other commit hash ID you chose, and *that* commit *doesn't* have that file.

You may wish to go back to having untracked files, and keeping them that way.  Untracked files do not get removed or shuffled-about like this.  Of course untracked files also are not in each *new* commit and will not appear in clones, so maybe you *don't* want to have them untracked.  Or maybe you want them to be in some commits and not be in others, and still get them back when you check out one of these other commits.

#### How to get your files back after switching to some other commit

As long as any given file is *untracked*—not in Git's index—then switching from this commit to that one won't remove it (though you'll get an interesting gripe):

```
$ git rm --cached file
rm 'file'
$ git checkout HEAD^
error: The following untracked working tree files would be removed by checkout:
        file
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

This happens because the difference between the current *commit*, in my case `8969ef2`, and the target one `bb2af52`, requires removing file `file`.  I added and committed file `file` in commit `8969ef2`.

So, I could now `mv file file.keep`, `git checkout HEAD^`, and `mv file.keep file`.  Now it's an untracked file while I work on commit `bb2af52` as a detached HEAD.

As an alternative, I can do this:

```
$ git restore --staged file
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

(This particular `git restore` command came straight out of `git status`, as its advice for undoing my to-be-committed removal.  Other commands, such as `git reset -- file`, would have worked as well.)

```
$ git checkout HEAD^
Note: switching to 'HEAD^'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
...
HEAD is now at bb2af52 initial
```

My checkout has now succeeded, but I no longer have file `file` in my work-tree (nor, of course, in Git's index).  Now I get it back using the hash ID `8969ef2` or the branch name `master`:

```
$ git restore --source master file
$ git status
HEAD detached at bb2af52
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        file

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

There is my file named `file`, back in my work-tree as an untracked file, copied out of the commit I chose.  If you don't have Git 2.23 or later, use:

```
git show master:file > file
```

rather than

```
git restore --source master file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try clearing the .gitignore cache for a file / folder
using command
git rm --cached filename

Comment: That is… not a helpful explanation, I'm afraid. `git rm --cached FILE` stages the removal of FILE, without removing it from the working tree. I would want to see a *lot* more explanation of why you're recommending this, before believing that it answers the question.